# Making a "min" command in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

im trying to make a commmand as : min $t1,$t2,$t3

$t1 will get the absolute value of the min value  between $t2 & $t3

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done without using any branches:

```
slt $t1,$t2,$t3
sub $t1,$zero,$t1  # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0
or $t4,$t3,$t1     # t4 = (t2 < t3) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : t3
xor $t4,$t4,$t1    # t4 = (t2 < t3) ? 0 : t3
and $t1, $t1, $t2  # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? t2 : 0
or $t1, $t1, $t4   # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? t2 : t3
```

Another alternative:

```
or $t4,$zero,$zero
slt $t1,$t2,$t3
movn $t4,$t3,$t1  # t4 = (t2 < t3) ? t3 : 0
movn $t1,$t2,$t1  # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? t2 : 0
xor $t1,$t1,$t4   # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? (t2 ^ t3) : 0
xor $t1,$t1,$t3   # t1 = (t2 < t3) ? t2 : t3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of signed `min()`, without the `abs()` special case that the question asks for.  Hopefully useful for people who don't need that part:

```
slt $at, $t2, $t3
add $t1, $t3, $zero
movn $t1, $t2, $at
```

I think this is the best way...

Answer (score 0):

hey guys found the answer

```
slt $t1,$t2,$t3
bne $t1,1,label
addi $t1,$t2,0
j exit
label: addi $t1,$t3,0
exit:
```

hope it helps